# How to search and extract string from command output?

Tags: shell-script, shell

**OS:** Kernel 2.6.x

**Utilities:** From busybox 1.2x

A command outputs multiple lines of text.

```
string1 text1: "asdfs asdf adfas"
string2 text2: "iojksdfa kdfj adsfj;"
string3 text3: "skidslk sadfj"
string4 text4: "lkpird sdfd"
string5 text5: "alskjfdsd safsd"
```

**Goal:** I need to search for the line that contains "text4: " (no quotes) and then extract all characters after that string to the end of the line.

**Desired Output:** "lkpird sdfd" (with quotes)

Currently I have ...

```
command | grep 'text4:' | awk -F': ' '{print $3}'
```

Is there a simpler way to write this ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Using sed

```
$ command | sed -n 's/.*text4://p'
 "lkpird sdfd"
```

`-n` tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.  `s/.*text4://`  tells sed to remove any text from the beginning of the line to the final occurrence of `text4:`.  If such a line is found, then the `p` tells sed to print it.

#### Using `grep -P`

```
$ command | grep -oP '(?<=text4:).*' 
 "lkpird sdfd"
```

`-o` tells grep to print only the matching part.  `(?<=text4:).*` matches any text that follows `text4:` but does not include the `text4:`.

*The `-P` option requires GNU grep.*  Thus, it will not work with busybox's builtin `grep`, nor with the default `grep` on BSD/Mac OSX systems.

#### Using awk

The original grep-awk solution can be simplified:

```
$ command | awk -F': ' '/text4: /{print $2}'
"lkpird sdfd"
```

#### Using awk (alternate)

```
$ command | awk '/text4:/{sub(/.*text4:/, ""); print}'
 "lkpird sdfd"
```

`/text4:/` selects lines that contain `text4:`.  `sub(/.*text4:/, "")` tells awk to remove all text from the beginning of the line to the last occurrence of `text4:` on the line.  `print` tells awk to print those lines.

Comment: In the sed example, does the period specify the beginning of the line ?

Comment: Added the space character after "text4:"

Comment: @uihdff In regular expressions, `.` means any character and `.*` means zero or more of any characters.  In sed, regular expressions match the _left-most longest_.  That means that `.*something` will always match from the beginning of the line because that gives the left-most longest match.  If you want to specify the beginning of a line anyway, use `^` as in `^.*something`.

Answer (score 5):

With `grep` and its PCRE support and `\K` notify.

```
command |grep -Po 'text4: \K.*'
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Unfortunately, I have to work with the functionality provided via busybox 1.25 which doesn't support the -P option.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know busyBox doesn't have `-P` with `grep`, but you have great [John's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393949/72456) with `sed` and `awk` only